# Python Dataframe editing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I wanna replace `( [` with `([`.
Essentially get rid of the space between the brackets.
But `df.replace()` does not work.
Even if the code executes
the output remains the same.

## Code

```
cdf=cdf.replace('( [','([')
```

`cdf` is a dataframe with 3 columns.

There is non error, its just that the replacing is not happening.

Comment: "*even if the code executes the output remains the same*" -> please provide the exact code that you used and a minimal example. Chances are that you used incorrect parameters or forgot to assign back the result

Comment: Post your code instead of posting the question twice.

Comment: Can you specify your question with example code or even an error message?

Comment: what are you editing?  A string cell, or the display of the whole frame?

Comment: Im trying to replace [ ( with [( in  the all the rows of the 3rd columns

Comment: "*cdf is a dataframe with 3 columns*" -> please provide a reproducible sample (**as code**), sufficient to reproduce the issue

Comment: So you are trying to use https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you question right, then the `df.applymap(mapping)` function is what you are searching for. It applies the `mapping` (for example a lambda) to all cells of you data frame. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"c1": ["Test", "Test[ (Test)]"],
        "c2": ["Test", "Test[ (Test)]"],
        "c3": ["Test", "Test[ (Test)]"]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

filtered = df.applymap(lambda s : s.replace("[ (", "[("))

print(filtered)
```

And this is the result:

```
             c1            c2            c3
0          Test          Test          Test
1  Test[(Test)]  Test[(Test)]  Test[(Test)]
```